# DJANGO: No module named social_auth.backends.contrib.github

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-social-auth

I had this error when I tried to sign in using github auth backend

```
No module named social_auth.backends.contrib.github
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_auth.backends.contrib.github.GithubBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'social.backends.github.GithubOAuth2',
)
```

for [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth)